# The code execution cannot proceed because ... was not found

Tags: windows, rust

Исходный код программы:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Пытаюсь скомпилировать со статической линковкой, но получаю окно с ошибкой:

```
The code execution cannot be proceed because std-66ce4ddf5a45ca83.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
```

Не понимаю в чем дело, догадываюсь что проблема с библиотекой, но как именно исправить это я не знаю.

Comment: Что значит со статической линковкой? Rust по умолчанию делает файлы с зависимостями только от `kernel` и `vcruntime`. Таргет у вас какой? `rustup show` что пишет?

Comment: @aSpex Default host: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc | Active toolchain: stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)

Comment: А компилируете как? Просто `cargo build`? 
Вообще эта dll должна быть в папке с бинарниками Раста. Проверьте есть она там на самом деле. Путь можно узнать с помощью команды `rustc --print sysroot`.
Проверьте есть в переменной `PATH` путь `c:\Users\%Name%\.cargo\bin` Попробуйте переустановить Раст.

Comment: А кстати  у вас Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools 2017 установлен? Или Visual Studio какая-нибудь? Еще можно попробовать переключиться на `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`.

Comment: @aSpex да, стоит visual studio 2017, компилирую обычным `cargo build`, посмотрел по пути `.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin` и действительно там лежит эта `.dll`, в PATH стоит путь `C:\Users\%Name%\.cargo\bin` . Всё должно идеально работать, но не работает ...

Comment: Попробуйте перейти на gnu. `rustup default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`, затем `rustup update`.
А в имени пользователя у вас нет не латинских символов? Этот баг вроде пофиксили давно и проявлялся он кажется по другому. В этом случае можно попробовать перенести растовые бинарники в другую папку - нужно задать переменную %RUSTUP_HOME% https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup.rs#environment-variables